# Understanding Google Calender recurring events

Tags: google-calendar-api, recurring-events

I have got Google calender recurring events like that:

a:1:{i:0;s:61:"RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20130618T132500Z;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR";}

or

a:1:{i:0;s:49:"RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20131123T210000Z;BYDAY=SA";}

I found the a lot of information on understading RRULE, but I don't know what does the strings in the beginning **a:1:{1:0;s:61:**    mean.  And I couldn't find information on that part.

Does anyone familiar with Google calendar tell me what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is serialized data. If you unserialize it you'll see that it's an array containing the RRULE string.